# How can I find specified data in a excel row using access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to find specified data in a excel row. Like from row range A1:A1J, only one cell is having data "Process" . if i find that data in a given range, i need to pop up the message "Found" Here is my code

```
         Dim ExcelApp As New Excel.Application
         Dim ExcelBook As New Excel.Workbook
         Dim rng As Excel.Range
         Dim rngDefine As Excel.Range

         Set ExcelBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C\temp\find.xlsm")
         ExcelApp.Visible = False       
        'Define your own Range
         Set rngDefine = ExcelBook.Worksheets("Datatab").Range("A1:AJ1")

         'ExcelBook.Worksheets("Datatab").Range ("A1:AJ1")

         Set c = .Find("Process", LookIn:=xlValues)
         For Each rng In rngDefine
         If c = "Process" Then
         MsgBox "Found"
         End If
           Next

         ExcelApp.Quit
         Set ExcelApp = Nothing
```

Not working. Any furthur code i need to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First approach** (slighlty faster):

```
Set rngDefine = ExcelBook.Worksheets("Datatab").Range("A1:AJ1")

If IsError(ExcelApp.Match("Process", rngDefine, 0)) Then
    MsgBox "Not found"
Else
    MsgBox "Found"
End If
```

**Second approach:**

```
Dim c As Excel.Range

Set rngDefine = ExcelBook.Worksheets("Datatab").Range("A1:AJ1")

Set c = rngDefine.Find(What:="Process", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

If c Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Not found"
Else
    MsgBox "Found"
End If
```

Comment: Both approaches worked great. Thank you so much. BTW how can i be able to delete that row contains "process" data.

Comment: row or column? in your case simplier would be to use second approach and write: `c.EntireColumn.Delete` (or `EntireRow` for deleting row)